# Window aggregations

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I'm testing different Queries in Azure Stream Analytics, but I'm having a hard time figuring out what happens using different combinations of Window (tumbling, hopping, sliding & session) and TIMESTAMP BY

I'd expect EnqueueTime (when data was put into an eventqueue/blobstore) to be used as default (if not specifying any TIMESTAMP By), System.Time if TIMESTAMP BY System.Time and DataTime if specifying some Time property inside the data stream.

Though, based on my tests it doesn't seem to be that way....

Anyone who can explain it.. I have a hard time understanding the documentation....

Answer (score 0):

EnqueuedTime is indeed the default time (EventEnqueuedUtcTime for Event Hub, or IoTHub.EnqueuedTime for IoT Hub).

When you select System.Time in combination with a time window, it will return the end of the window.

What do you observe in your tests? Let me know how we can help.

Thanks,
JS (Stream Analytics team)